# searching a list<String> in a list<string> model in flutter

Tags: flutter, search, arraylist

I have been working on a LLM-like very simple project in Flutter. I need to find a string list, for example "what is my lecture score" in a list data. But the order doesn't matter.
If my search finds the "what", "is", "my", "lecture", "score" in one of the sentence list in any order, the result will be true, otherwise false.

Here is my sentence list as a List:

```
class vaModel {
  final int id;
  final List<String> stringData;
  final String response;

vaModel({
  required this.id,
  required this.stringData,
  required this.response,
 });
}
```

and here is the data of this model:

```
import "package:flut2deneme/pages/vaModel.dart";

List<vaModel> vaData = [
 vaModel(id: 1, stringData: ["what", "my", "score", "lecture"], response: "load1"),
 vaModel(id: 2, stringData: ["total", "lectures", "hours", "week"], response: "load2"),
 vaModel(id: 3, stringData: ["how", "much", "cost"], response: "load3"),
 //other
];
```

for example, if the user enters "what my score is for this lecture", it will return "load1" in id:1 in the vaData list. Because however the order is different and it has more other words, the desired words (what, my, score, lecture) are found in the data list. As seen, there are other words in the received sentence and the words are not in given order, the result is true, since all required words exist in item 1 (id:1)

It may also be explained in searching a list<> in a list of List<>.

Thank you for any support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
String? getResponse(String input){
  for (final model in vaData) {
    if (model.stringData.every((element) => input.toLowerCase().contains(element))) {
      return model.response;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Example:

```
void main() {
  print(getResponse("What is my score in the lecture")); //load1
  print(getResponse("Score in the lecture what my")); // load1
  print(getResponse("Score in the  what my")); // null
  print(getResponse("How much does it cost?")); // load3
}
```